# asynchronous function in a php api

Tags: php, api, asynchronous

I hope you can help me

I have an api in php implemented in azure web app service.

I need it to do a loaded script and it lags, before it returns a 500 error within a minute of calling it

I need you to make a script, the script makes a lot of http calls, calculates things and finally sends results to a database. the script (takes 15 min to 2 hours) depending on the input you have, the code is as follows:

```
public function get() {

        $params = http_build_query($this->request['params']);

        /* -- start script --

         script takes 15 min to 2 hours depending on input $ params
         I need the script to finish before the http call dies 
       */

          $meli = new Meli;
          $meli -> data_extractor($params);

        /* -- end script -- */

        $this->response = array('Response' => ' script has started working');
        $this->responseStatus = 200;
    }
```

the problem I have is that when I call the api a few minutes after calling it it returns 500 error without having finished the script.

Comment: For such long running tasks, you need some sort of background workers. Look into a queue/worker system like Gearman, ØMQ or simply a cron job with a database job queue. The web request would then create a job object (something saved in the database) which gets worked on by the workers, and you can query the status of it through HTTP (and get its result once done).

Comment: what I was looking for is for the get () function to work as in nodejs, where it would return the result => ' script has started to work' before finishing the script, because it would run asynchronously, I think it is the term.Thank you